# Eclipse Tab key for code autocompletion instead of the Enter key for Java?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist

I've read many questions and similar issues, but I can't seem to find an answer on how to achieve the effect of having the Tab key input the suggested content from the content assist as Enter does while coding.

I've tried changing the binding in Window/Preferences/General/Keys -> Word Completion and Content Assist to Tab, but it didn't work.

Comment: Those are keybindings for opening the assist, not for inserting a proposal.

Answer (score 0):

In the preferences *General > Keys* **change only** the binding for the command ***Content Assist*** from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to <kbd>Tab</kbd>, **not** the binding for the command ***Word Completion***.

Otherwise, <kbd>Tab</kbd> would trigger only *Word Completion* as it has the more specific scope (*When: Editing Text* vs. *When: In Dialogs and Windows*), not both commands.

Comment: Changing the binding in Content Assist from Ctrl + Space to Tab will only modify it to switch between proposal templates. I want to achieve an effect where pressing the Tab key will insert selected proposal into the code.

Comment: I see. I don't think the keys to choose a content assist proposal can be modified. In preferences _Java > Editor > Content Assist_, there is only the option _Disable insertion triggers except 'Enter'_ (if disabled, a proposal can be chosen with the `Enter` or with the `Space` key).